# Data formatting in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know if there is a possibility to modify these dates (they are in PT-BR), I want to put them in numerical form in EN or PT-BR.

```
                    Início                      Fim
0      15 de março de 1985  14 de fevereiro de 1986
1  14 de fevereiro de 1986   23 de novembro de 1987
2   23 de novembro de 1987    15 de janeiro de 1989
3    16 de janeiro de 1989      14 de março de 1990
4      15 de março de 1990    23 de janeiro de 1992
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [`setlocale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) `LC_TIME` to `pt_PT` then [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) will work as expected with a format string:

```
import locale

import pandas as pd

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'pt_PT')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Início': ['15 de março de 1985', '14 de fevereiro de 1986',
               '23 de novembro de 1987', '16 de janeiro de 1989',
               '15 de março de 1990'],
    'Fim': ['14 de fevereiro de 1986', '23 de novembro de 1987',
            '15 de janeiro de 1989', '14 de março de 1990',
            '23 de janeiro de 1992']
})
cols = ['Início', 'Fim']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d de %B de %Y')
```

`df`:

```
      Início        Fim
0 1985-03-15 1986-02-14
1 1986-02-14 1987-11-23
2 1987-11-23 1989-01-15
3 1989-01-16 1990-03-14
4 1990-03-15 1992-01-23
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the string inside each cell by " de ".
2. Replace the 2nd element with the corresponding number (I suggest using a dictionary for this).
3. Join the list into a string. I suggest using `str.join`, but string concatenation or formatted strings work too.

Let's use an example.

```
    date = "23 de novembro de 1987"
    dates = date.split(" de ") # ['23', 'novembro', '1987']
    dates[1] = "11" # ['23', '11', '1987']
    numerical_date = '/'.join(dates) # "23/11/1987"
```